# Drawing unity 3D Map based on real world map

Tags: unity-game-engine, mapbox

I'm using `mapbox` SDK for unity. I'm trying to build a 3D map based on a real world map.

`mapbox` have some really nice features but all areas are not implemented yet, such as deserts in Saudi Arabia.

Does anyone have an idea about how can I elevate the desert into beautiful 3D map using `mapbox`?

Or do you know any other SDK for unity that can help me with this?

> **Please note that I need to use real world coordinates (Longitude,**
>   **Latitude) in my game, Pins will be inserted on map based on real world**
>   **coordinates.**

Comment: Is this useful? https://blogs.bing.com/maps/2019-09/get-up-and-running-with-the-maps-sdk-for-unity

Comment: Did you look at https://docs.mapbox.com/unity/maps/overview/custom-maps/  I'm also working on a project with visualization real world. Unfortunately, I rejected using mapbox since it's pretty poor for now.

Comment: Also https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/maps-platform/the-real-world-as-your-playground-build

Comment: @user14492 yes but bing map unity package is still not available for unity 2019.2

Comment: @user14492 and google maps sdk require some billing account

Comment: @Kamiky yes I've seen this overview already

Comment: What about using heightmaps? https://www.3d-map-generator.com/3d-map-generator-atlas-tools-heightmap-tools/

Comment: I've tried it, but I will lose the functionality of inserting a pin on a specific Longitude & Latitude (In other words: I will lose real world coordinates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Elevation Data Sources

There are multiple sources that provide elevation data. Bing Maps, Mapbox and ArgGIS (ESRI) are the most well-known services in that area. In rare cases like deserts some of them cover areas whereas the others do not. In your case if MapBox does not cover the Saudi-Arabian desert you can try out one of those other sources.

### Mixed Data Sources

In order so solve your problem within MapBox you have to first extract data from a viable source and provide it to MapBox. Fortunately MapBox supports third-party data: [MapBox: how to use custom data](https://docs.mapbox.com/unity/maps/overview/custom-maps/#use-custom-data)

There are also many third-party tools that you can use or learn from.
Have a look at this Asset from the Unity Asset Store for example: [Online Maps v3](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/online-maps-v3-138509)
This asset allows you to keep your MapBox style, cache the tiles locally to save cost, use multiple elevation sources, create 3D-buildings in cities and fill in relevant data from the google api.

### Missing Data

In order to have a globally working game you have to check multiple sources and use the one that has the elevation data that you want. Unfortunately, in some cases you won't find any data at all as it has not been mapped yet at all. In this case you have to exclude it from your game.